# Test if a big integer is a power of two

Tags: algorithm, biginteger

Given a *big* integer (stored in binary), how can I quickly test if it is a power of 2, i.e. equivalent to 2ᵏ for an integer exponent k?

A simple but rather slow method is to continuously divide by 2 till the number becomes 2 or there is a non-zero remainder. Unfortunately, we need to perform up to as many divisions as there are digits in our number.

For small integers, there are numerous solutions including bit-counting etc. I am interested in a fast solution for integers with an *arbitrary number of digits*. E.g. can we speed up above method by some fast integer division by 2 or other trickery?

Comment: Do you have access to the backing array of integers or do you have to go through some fixed set of operations (which?)

Comment: That's not very useful. But it's stored as BCD then? Step 1: convert it to proper binary.

Comment: `b = bin(i)`


`return (b.count('1') == 1)`

Comment: You must specify the details of the representation !

Comment: I still see no information about the representation.

Comment: I don't see "stored in binary" nowhere, are you kidding ?

Comment: Ok, do you mean a byte stream with all bits in the bytes used ? If yes, this is trivial, all bytes must be zero except for one, which is one of 8 possible cases. I couldn't imagine you were asking that !

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right, I was not asking that. Originally, I was asking about *decimal* integers. However, since all (good!) replies I got addressed binary integers, I changed the question to binary integers to the benefit of future readers with similar questions. As you can see, the answers partly go into technical / implementation detail and contribute valuable insight.

Comment: @harold You are right given typical use cases. However, converting to binary and then testing for power of 2 in binary might (?) be slower than just testing for power of 2 in decimal. Anyway, I changed my question now.

Comment: Actually, a good answer cannot be given without knowing the distribution of the numbers. Are they more often very similar to a power of 2, or very dissimilar ? What is the average number of ones ? Are they clustered ? ...

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are asking the right questions! Unfortunately, the distribution of our numbers is not known a priori (at least in my specific use case).

Comment: @le_m: mh, don't you have minimum insight on what this function is used for ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the fastest way is still by inspecting the bits. Assuming your number is x, in java you could do `x & (x - 1) == 0` if true then it would be a power of 2

For BigInteger you can do `x.and(x.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)`

Comment: I think you may have missed the part about big integers though. You can use this technique (it's not the best, but decent), but you couldn't write it that way in java

Comment: For small integers, yes. For big, arbitrary precision ones we would need to split them up into smaller units first, and then we might be able to cleverly combine the individual results back to a solution for the given big integer. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the BigInteger class allows bitwise operations

Comment: It does, but not with that syntax. That doesn't really matter since it's not fundamental, but that makes it look like you missed something

Comment: Updated the answer for BigInteger

Comment: shouldn't it be `.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)` instead of `==`?

Comment: While my question was originally about *decimal* (not binary) big integers, I modified it to fit your (good!) answers to the benefit of future readers with similar questions.

Comment: This is certainly not the fastest way for BigInteger. In particular, there is no need to explicitly compute (and store) `x - 1`.

Comment: `x & (x - 1) == 0` only has to be checked for the top limb of the BigInteger. I am not sure if you can access the single limbs of a BigInteger, otherwise you convert it to a byte array and check if the first byte (Java returns a big-endian result, AFAIK) fulfills the above equation. All others must be 0.

Comment: Note the precedence: `(x & (x - 1)) == 0`

Answer (score 3):

It would be suboptimal to subtract `1` from a large number, since at the CPU level there would be multiple operations including a carry for large numbers because the computation would not fit into the accumulator.

For computations on the CPU, the quickest way would be:

1. For each accumulator-sized set of bytes (8 bytes on a 64-bit number, 1 `LOAD` instruction)
2. Check if the number is zero (1 `CMP` instruction)
3. If not zero, copy the number to another register (1 `JNZ`instruction)
4. Subtract `1` from the number in the new register (1 `SUB` instruction)
5. AND the two registers (1 `AND` instruction)
6. If the value is zero, continue checking that the rest of the sets are purely zero. (1 `JZ` instruction)

To optimize, you'll need to split the number into such sets and do the comparison.

The key advantage of the above approach is: by doing step (2), we get rid of the large subtraction and carry. The subtraction in step (4) will take exactly one instruction and the comparison with zero will also take one instruction. So it should speed up the operation.

Comment: @harold Sorry, fixed.

Comment: After having implemented a BigInteger type in x86 assembler and Pascal, my exerience is that carries seldom propagate very far. And you can stop propagating once there is no carry anymore. So the solution `n & (n - 1) = 0` is a very good one. In my code, I simply check if all limbs *below* the top limb are 0 and if the top limb is a power of two (using the above equation). Checking for all limbs being 0 can easily and quickly be done with a `bitwise or` (of all those limbs), which does not require any branching. http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html.

Comment: Another very insightful answer addressing optimal low-level implementation. Depending on the target platform, your optimization strategy might come in handy!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis in this case it's a 'borrow'. I believe that has to propagate from the MSB to the LSB in case of a power of `2`, correct? In any case this solution does exactly what you mention: ignore the zeroes and subtract one from the non-zero set of bytes.

Comment: If there is no borrow, at a certain point, it will not propagate anymore. Just try it yourself.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, but the point is, for a pure power of 2, there will be a borrow all the way until the MSB.

Comment: Not if you only check the top limb/byte. The rest must simply be 0, all the way down.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ah yes, that's true. I was considering the two parts independently.

Answer (score 3):

For really big numbers, this test essentially amounts to comparing all bytes to zero, except for one of them which must hold a power of 2. We can focus on this test for zero, while efficiently checking for nonzero is less important.

The simplest form is by testing 32 or 64 bit integers (i.e. 4 or 8 bytes) for zero (depending on register size).

Faster can be achieved by means of SIMD intructions. Under SSE2 or AVX, you can fetch 16 or 32 bytes, compare to zero (`_mm256_cmpeq_epi8`/`_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` with a pre-cleared register) and pack to 16 or 32 bits using `_mm_movemask_epi8` or `_mm256_movemask_epi8`. Then, compare the resulting scalar (short or int) to all ones.

[Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to exist a corresponding `_mm512_movemask_epi8` in AVX512, which would allow to handle 64 bytes at a time.]

---

When you have found a group of bytes holding a nonzero value, you can test them one by one, using a lookup-table of 256 entries.

Using the SIMD approach, you can even speed this up by means of another lookup-table of 256 entries telling the index of the nonzero bit in a byte, or a reserved value when there are several nonzero bits. Using this lookup table twice or four times, you will know which among the 16 or 32 bits corresponds to a nonzero byte (and also detect several nonzero bytes).

Solutions exploiting the formula `n ^ (n - 1)` are also possible.

As already said, these micro-optimizations are probably worthless, except if most of your numbers aren't powers of 2.

Comment: Great answer naming specific SIMD instructions which are needed for a fast parallel implementation, and taking possible prior knowledge about the number in question into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you just need to verify if bit population of the whole big integer is `1` I guess that the fastest approach could be to store the big integer as an array of `uint32_t` or better `uint64_t` so that you can just use [`popcnt`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679649) x86 instruction.

There are also naive approaches as using SSE3 instruction `PSHUFB` as described [here](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html), and even [other approaches](https://danluu.com/assembly-intrinsics/) which still rely on `popcnt` but with hand written assembly.

Of course this could be overkill because you don't need the population count, but you need to know if it's exactly 1 but it maybe worth trying.

As always in such optimization problems, guessing is just irrelevant, the only option is to test different approaches and see what fits better.

Comment: Very insightful answer addressing optimal low-level implementation on typical architectures. Thanks!